# How to put x-grid on a plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a vector x = 1:20 and another vector y.

When I plot x versus y, the x-axis has labels in increments of 2. That is, x-axis shows, 0,2,4,6,8,...,20. But I want my x-axis to show 0,1,2,3,4,...,20.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend looking at this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html

If you have MATLAB version 2014b or later:

```
ax = gca;
ax.xTick = 0:20;
```

A more general solution that works with any version of MATLAB:

```
ax = gca;
set(ax, 'XTick', 0:20);
```

Comment: @Hoki Editing my post to mention that. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `XTick` property.  Assuming your figure is open, just do:

```
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:20);
```

Here's a quick example:

```
x = 1:20;
y = rand(1,20);
plot(x,y)
```

We get this plot:

[image]

Changing the `XTick` property on the graph gives us:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To modify the x and y grid on your plots, you can use the `XTick` and `YTick` as shown in the Matlab documentation [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html).